# "driving across the state" or "driving across state"?

Tags: phrases, determiners

Is it "driving across state" like "driving across town", or "driving across THE state", like "driving across the country"?

Comment: It's "driving across *the* state"; "driving *across town*" is a special case, because "[*across town*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/dict.aspx?rd=1&word=cross-town)" itself is a special idiom. Note that, for completely different reasons, you can correctly say "driving across state lines", so don't let that confuse you.

Comment: You can also say, "cross-state" and "cross-country"

Comment: There may well be significant local variations in how this is handled. In the UK, we would be unlikely to talk about 'driving across town'. We would more likely say either 'driving through town', or possibly 'through the town'. I can't think of any other instances where British speakers would drop the article with a specific place, such as 'county', 'district', 'area' etc. We might well say that someone was 'driving across fields', or 'across farmland', or 'across private land'. But those would naturally not call for a definite article since the specific place would not be mentioned.

Comment: We might say 'driving across London', or 'across Yorkshire'.

Comment: @WS2, in AmE, "across town" or "across New York [city *or* state]" is normal and common.

Comment: In the parts of the United States where I've lived (California, Maryland, New York, and Texas), the normal wording is "driving across the state." I don't remember ever having heard "driving across state" (with _across_ and without the definite article) in any of those states, though I agree with Jim that "driving cross-state" sounds okay, analogously to "driving cross-country."

Comment: @Sven Yargs 'Cross country' always has the 'off road' sense (ie 'country' = 'countryside') in the UK; is this the case in the US?

Comment: It can mean "off-road" in a sentence such as "He bought a Jeep so he could travel cross-country," but I would understand the sentence "He drove cross-country from San Francisco to Boston" to mean (most probably) driving for the most part on the Interstate Highway system.

Comment: For example: When I was young (living in New York) our family went on a cross-country trip for our vacation and visited my cousins in California.

Comment: Why the ***or,*** everything doesn't have to be only one way and not the other. Both are correct, grammatical, make sense and of course mean different things. There's no question for an answer here, right?

Comment: Please visit [ell.se] for questions about the definite article in general. Good Luck.

Comment: @Edwin That’s [not entirely true in the UK, either](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CrossCountry) (unless your trains operate in a _very_ different way to ours!).

Comment: @Janus Proper nouns aren't English. The first 70 Google returns I've just scanned included one non-capitalised 'across the country' usage, and that was in a CrossCountry train article. Most of the non-capitalised hits were for skiing, running or eventing.

Comment: @Edwin No, but the name implies that _cross-country_ also has the meaning ‘from one end of the country to the other’ in the UK. If it didn’t, the only connotation people would get from the name is of a train driving off the tracks into the fields—hardly a good way to gain passengers. There are also instances like [gov.uk talking about “intercity, suburban and cross-country trains”](https://www.gov.uk/transport-disabled/trains) that imply that this is so. This sense is more common in AmE, but it’s not nonexistent in BrE either.

Comment: @Janus 'Cross country' in the vast majority of distinct cases has the 'off road' sense (ie 'country' = 'countryside') in the UK. Probably, usages meaning 'involving travel across GB, usually generally E-W or W-E' are deliberate slightly cheeky broadenings, usually railway-driven (especially in 'CrossCountryTrains.co.uk ') – the language being railroaded.

Answer (score 1):

[The more common usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=driving+across+state%2Cdriving+across+the+state&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdriving%20across%20state%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdriving%20across%20the%20state%3B%2Cc0) is "across the state." Referring to "state" without using "the" will typically mean a state level competition:

> Our debate team is going to state.

---

"Town" is different and does not require "the":

> I am going to town.
>
> I am driving across town.
>
> I am driving through town.
>
> I left town.

---

"Country", as you noted, requires "the":

> I am driving across the country.

Answer (score 1):

"Driving across the state" means pretty much traversing the entire state, from border to border (and, perhaps, then some).  "Driving across state" implies driving a large distance within the state, but likely ending up somewhere within the state (not necessarily near a border).

"I'm in Kansas, driving across the state on my way to California."

"I'm driving across state to the wrestling match in Topeka."